# how to find out that user is in north or south part of america from Mason Dixon Line?

Tags: android, gps, android-gps

This is a Mason dixon line in America , which divide north and south america.
[image]

When I fetch user current location from GPS, I can easily convert from Lat/Long to his actual address, but not able to find out wheather user is in north or south part of america. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

1.) Find out the corner coordinates of the mason dixie line, finally you end uo in a poly line of (lat,lon) coordinates.

2.) extend the mason dixie line to continue and surround south america, now you have a dicon south polygon (you make this polygon rough with a few point in the ocean, no need for precise line along the coast line.

3.) do the same with north america.

Now you have two polygons sharing and touching at the mason dixie line.
Now Just use a point-in-polygon algorithm to find outh in which polygon the point is located. use x for longitude and y for latitude.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a polygon (closed area) with Dixon's corner coordinates (you can create the polygon "drawing" up/north or down/south).

2) Create a method to return if the lat/long is inside of the polygon boundaries (a point inside the polygon area). If the point is not in the polygon area, it is in the other side (of course if we consider getting only coordinates inside America. Otherwise you can do as @AlexWien said).

Comment: @AlexWien I would like to talk to you. Can you e-mail me please?